# ios SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock error process

Tags: ios, callback

i use the SKStoreProductViewController,when pass the right id to the method **loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock:**,it all goes very well ,but when pass a wrong id to this method,it doesn't callback the completionBlock with error message.

Comment: This seems to be fixed on iOS7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We saw this as well. By trial-and-error we deduced that presenting the store kit view controller *after* the call to loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock: made the completion block run.